# AttributeConverter class registered multiple times when using Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I have an application that used to work fine using both STS and maven command line. 
After a change in the code, where  a new AttributeConverter was added, it is not working anymore. I'm still able to build and run it using maven command line, but it doesn't run on eclipse. It keep raising the same error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class com.mycompany.communication.model.EncryptionConverter] registered multiple times
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at com.mycompany.service.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:126) [classes/:?]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class com.mycompany.communication.model.EncryptionConverter] registered multiple times
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:353) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl$AttributeConverterManager.addAttributeConverter(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:321) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ...
```

The new AtrributeConverter (EncryptionConverter) is only used in one class. Does someone have an idea what could be wrong here?
why does it work using the command line (mvn spring-boot:run), but not using eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate 5.0.11 - AttributeConverter class registered mulitple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742221/hibernate-5-0-11-attributeconverter-class-registered-mulitple-times)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your workspace? Sometimes leftover .class files cause issues when spring detect them at runtime even though you can't see the source .java file

Comment: I already  created another workspace,  deleted the contets of the .m2\repository, but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, but  `@SpringBootapplication` and `@ComponentScan` with some paths included.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and in my case this was caused by the fact that I had two references to the same Module containing the Converter.

Go to "Project Structure"(⌘;) / Modules / Dependencies and ensure you don't have two dependencies that are really the same. In my case, I had:

- one direct IntelliJ reference to the module containing the Converter
- and another to the Jar of the same module.

Comment: Solve similar issue by ```mvn clean verify compile``` command