# Spring boot 1.5.4 to 2.0.4 AttributeConverter registered multiple times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am aware of the following answer:

[Hibernate 5.0.11 - AttributeConverter class registered mulitple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742221/hibernate-5-0-11-attributeconverter-class-registered-mulitple-times)

But it isn't solving my problem. I'm upgrading Spring Boot from 1.5.4 to 2.0.4 and I'm getting

```
AttributeConverter class [class com.foo.CalculationModeConverter] registered multiple times
```

None of the code around converters has changed during the upgrade. Hibernate is registered at `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.17.Final` according to the `dependencies` task.

Answer (score 1):

All of my converters were annotated with `@Converter` and entities used `@Convert` on properties. This seems to now cause a double registration. I removed `@Converter` and all is well thus far. I still want to find the documentation on when this changed.