# Hibernate 5 and Spring Boot 2 - AttributeConverter class registered multiple times

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, intellij-idea, hibernate-5.x

In my Spring Boot application I have a simple JPA `AttributeConverter` declared like:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class GenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<Gender, String> {...}
```

and applied like:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Column(length = 1, nullable = false)
    private Gender gender;
    // ...
}
```

If I use IntelliJ IDEA run/debug configuration for launching the Spring Boot app, the context initialization fails because of `AssertionFailure` exception. If I use `gradle clean bootRun` the app is launched successfully. So it seems like a bug in IDE or an error in project settings.

I debugged and dumped stacktraces of two subsequent registrations of the Converter, but I still don't understand why it happens twice. Kindly analyze the stacktraces.

First time registration (no error):

```
  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.AttributeConverterManager.addConverter(AttributeConverterManager.java:44)
  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:353)
  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861)
  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$122.379121284.getObject(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
....
```

Second-time registration (error!):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: AttributeConverter class [class by.naxa.example.conversion.GenderConverter] registered multiple times
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.AttributeConverterManager.addConverter(AttributeConverterManager.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:353) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl$AttributeConverterManager.addAttributeConverter(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:325) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ....
```

I can include `gradle :dependencyInsight --dependency jpa` output or screenshot of my Project Structure > Modules if you think it may be helpful.

I know there's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40742221/1429387) but the accepted solution doesn't help me. I don't use `@EnableAutoconfiguration` annotation. My main class is as easy as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MysqlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MysqlApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an issue with IntelliJ IDEA and Spring Boot [Dev Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/runner.html). The following steps helped me to resolve this issue in Windows 10.

1. Open settings <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Go to Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | [Runner](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/runner.html)
3. Uncheck Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle

Now try to run Debug configuration again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an issue with IntelliJ IDEA and Spring Boot [Dev Tools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html). The following steps helped me to resolve this issue in Ubuntu, but not in Windows 10.

1. Remove `devtools` dependency from build.gradle:

```groovy
    // runtimeClasspath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-devtools'
```

2. Build > Clean project
3. Close IntelliJ IDEA:

   File > Exit
4. Execute `gradle clean`
5. Delete folders from the project root folder: build, out, .gradle:

```sh
    rm -rf build out .gradle
```

6. Clean system cache:

   Launch IntelliJ IDEA and go to menu File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
7. Wait while IntelliJ updates indices

Now try to run Debug configuration again. It will take a while to rebuild the project, but then it should launch successfully.